# Ambient temperature sensor peugeot 207cc 2014

Tags: electrical, sensor, peugeot, peugeot-207

My ambient temperature sensor reading always in - so had the sensor replaced and its still showing the same fault. Peugeot 207cc 2014. Can you reset this or can someone help me and tell me what's wrong. Code is P0070. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Tha code reports that there's a problem with an ambient temperature sensor circuit. This could be caused by the sensor itself or the wiring or dirty \corroded connectors. Least likely would be the PCM. Not familiar with your specific vehicle, but if you got a wiring schematic, you can test the circuits. Generally one circuit would have 5 volts reference voltage and ground, and the other would have signal voltage that will change with change of temperature by something like a hair dryer. If the signal changes while applying heat when testing at the sensor, the sensor is good. Then test the voltage differential at the PCM. If there is no voltage change when heat is applied to sensor then there's bad connections or wiring. Usually the problem is found by this point.